# Add Mootools 1.3 element to document body

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, mootools

I have tried using the inject, adopt and grab methods to insert my new element into the document body, however it does not seem to be working.

What I really want it to do is to create a new div that displays over the top of all the other elements in the body. I have it working in a previous iteration of mootools however am unable to get it working in 1.3.

Just thought I would see if anybody had some ideas on here that could help, Cheers!

```
  var overlay = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'overlay',
    styles: {
      display: 'block',
      visibility: 'visible',
      position: 'fixed',
      background-color: '#4E5056',
      z-index: 65555,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }
  });

  $(document.body).inject(overlay);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can benefit from using jshint/jslint.

you cannot leave `background-color` and `z-index` like that, use " " around them or use the scripting versions of `backgroundColor` and `zIndex`.

output of jslint:

> Error:
>
> Problem at line 7 character 17:
>   Expected ':' and instead saw '-'.
>
> background-color: '#4E5056',
>
> Problem at line 7 character 23:
>   Expected '}' to match '{' from line 3
>   and instead saw ':'.
>
> background-color: '#4E5056',
>
> Problem at line 7 character 25:
>   Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1
>   and instead saw '#4E5056'.
>
> background-color: '#4E5056',
>
> Problem at line 8 character 14:
>   Expected ')' and instead saw ':'.
>
> z-index: 65555,
>
> Problem at line 8 character 15:
>   Missing semicolon.
>
> z-index: 65555,
>
> Problem at line 8 character 16:
>   Expected an assignment or function
>   call and instead saw an expression.
>
> z-index: 65555,
>
> Problem at line 8 character 21:
>   Missing semicolon.
>
> z-index: 65555,
>
> Problem at line 8 character 21:
>   Expected an identifier and instead saw
>   ','.
>
> z-index: 65555,
>
> Problem at line 8 character 21:
>   Stopping, unable to continue. (53%
>   scanned).

do you not have a debugger? web inspector in chrome/webkit or firebug in firefox clearly show the exception:

```
missing : after property id
[Break On This Error] background-color: '#4E5056',
```

and finally, injecting:

```
element.inject(document.body);
// or
$(document.body).adopt(element);
```

look at jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/SW3pK/

you can click the jslint button there to verify the code too.

Comment: wow thats great, never heard of jshint/jslint before. Defiantly using them in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
overlay.inject(document.body);
```

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:inject

You also should write properties always in ' or " like Dimitar said.

Example:

```
{
    'display': 'block',
    'background-color': '#F00'
}
```